# Creating an update statement from a nested select

Tags: mysql, sql

I have a mysql statement below

```
select c11 as genre, t3.strGenre, t2.idGenre t2idGenre, t1.idMVideo
from musicvideo t1
join genrelinkmusicvideo t2
on t2.idMVideo=t1.idMVideo
join genre t3
on t3.idGenre=t2.idGenre
where not (c11=strGenre) and genre='Alternative Rock'
```

This works fine and gives me the desired results.

Now when I want to put this into an update statement i get stuck.

```
update t2
set idGenre=62
where (select c11, t3.strGenre, t2.idGenre t2idGenre
from musicvideo t1
join genrelinkmusicvideo t2
on t2.idMVideo=t1.idMVideo
join genre t3
on t3.idGenre=t2.idGenre
where not (c11=strGenre) and genre='Alternative Rock')
```

I know this is not correct.  Any help would be appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

Try:

```
update genrelinkmusicvideo t2
    join musicvideo t1
       on t2.idMVideo = t1.idMVideo
    join genre t3
       on t3.idGenre = t2.idGenre
set t2.idGenre = 62
where c11 <> strGenre and genre = 'Alternative Rock'
```

FYI, I would recommend using table_alias.column (e.g. `t3.genre = 'Alternative Rock'`), since it makes thing much more clear, particularly for those who do not know the schema already.

Answer (score 0):

You could try:

```
update genrelinkmusicvideo 
set idGenre=62
where idGenre IN (select  t2.idGenre 
from musicvideo t1
join genrelinkmusicvideo t2
on t2.idMVideo=t1.idMVideo
join genre t3
on t3.idGenre=t2.idGenre
where not (c11=strGenre) and genre='Alternative Rock')
```